# JMeter: Response too large to be displayed

Tags: jmeter, response

In JMeter, I have been experiencing "Response too large to be displayed. Size: 443216 > Max: 204800" error in the response data most often.

Is there any way to get rid of this response?

I tried adding **view.results.tree.max_size=0** in user.properties file but still the same issue.

Do I need to add "**#view.results.tree.max_size=0**" in user.properties file? or "**view.results.tree.max_size=0**" is fine?

**Or can this response be ignored?**

Comment: I hope you already restarted Jmeter after making that change. Right?

Comment: Thanks Incognito! Restarted and works now.

Comment: I will add this as an answer you might want to accept it so that the question can be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not restarted Jmeter after making the change, restart it and the changes will take into effect.